# jquery div box appear on top of button

Tags: jquery

heres the fiddle I'm working on 
http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/22cTn/

Im trying to get the box to appear on top of the button but on the bottom of the exisiting div box.

```
  <div id="top_form">
  <form>
    Street: <input name="titles[]" type="text" placeholder="eg: 123 Fake st."><br><br>
    City: <input name="titles[]" type="text" placeholder="eg: Bellflower">
    <select>
    <option value=" ">State</option>
    <option value="ca">CA</option>
    <option value="az">AZ</option>
    <option value="de">DE</option>
  </select>
     Zip: <input name="titles[]" type="text" placeholder="eg: 91745"><br />

 </form>

 </div>
    <br />
 <a id="awsomeButton" href="#">+ Add Loction</a>
```

Heres the script

```
var tpl = ""
 + "<div id='location_div_<%= id %>'><h1>My Location #<%= id %></h1></div>";

  var newId = new Date().getTime();
 var template = _.template(tpl);
   var compiled = template({id: newId});

 var form = ""
+ "<div id='added_form'><a href='#' class='close_btn'>x</a><form> Street: <input       name='titles' type='text'><br /><br />City: <input name='titles' type='text'><select><option value=' '>State</option><option value='ca'>CA</option></select>Zip: <input name='titles' type='text'></form></div>"


 $('#awsomeButton').on('click', 
    function(e){
    $(form).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't use a fixed id attribute on any of the elements you are adding to the page, because it can be added multiple times and ids are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
.appendTo('body')
```

**append** it to

```
.appendTo('#top_form')
```

Better to encase your top_form in another div

```
<div id="container" >
    <div id="top_form">
```

And append it to the container...

```
.appendTo('#container')
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/22cTn/5/)**

Comment: i kind of did that but i added the container div on the bottom of the top_form id http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/22cTn/6/  is that ok to do?

Comment: Sure.. you can do that , but it makes more sense to have them all together.. Also `ID's` in aHTML page are supposed to be uniques. Replace them with a class instead